# Rails accessing an API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, design-patterns

Im using [Httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) to access COLOURlovers API. But im looking to do this in a rails way.
I've managed it to work by creating a class on `app/models/clover.rb`:

```
require 'httparty'
class Clover
  include HTTParty

  base_uri 'www.colourlovers.com/api'
```

and then i've defined methods such as:

```
  def self.random(resource)
    fix_params query
    response = get("/#{resource}/random", { query: query })
    ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response.body)
  end
```

then i query for a resource like:

```
Clover.random :color
```

It does the job, but im not sure this is a good way to solving this problem. Is there a design-pattern to this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I would extract the http stuff into its own class/module, including the parsing of the response, then inherit into your actual model class so the model is only ever dealing with the resource itself, not the the communication/parsing.